# Entity Framework core Code First and MySql DateTime precision?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, code-first

I'm using EF core with the latest MySql .Net Connector in Code First and I can't find how to set my DateTime column precision to 6, it always seems to be 0 (no milliseconds)!

I tried:

```
dbModelBuilder.Entity<InstructionsCxl>().Property(InstructionsCxl => InstructionsCxl.Instantiated)
                .HasColumnType("DATETIME");
```

Comment: Does your MySQL version support precision for datetime fields?

Comment: indeed it does, I'm in the midst of migrating this from EF where I had been using:dbModelBuilder.Entity<InstructionsCxl>().Property(InstructionsCxl => InstructionsCxl.Instantiated)
                .HasPrecision(6);

Comment: 8.0.16 is the version of MySQL that I'm targeting